# Is there an SDK to develop for Samsung Gear Fit

Tags: android

Has Samsung released an SDK to develop for the Gear Fit. I want to develop and app for the Gear fit approximately 80% of  the websites i have visited say that the SDK is not open.

Comment: Based on Samsung developer forums there doesn't seem to be movement to have it publicly available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the SDK is not distributed by Samsung. You can get it elsewhere. Try this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/gear-fit/development/samsung-gear-fit-sdk-available-t2872803